# SVG linear Gradient & fill = URL(#grayGradient) is not working in LWC

Tags: css, svg, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

When I am trying to use the below code & dynamically pass the value to render the bar it does not show the svg with color :
below is the code for refrence

```
<template>
    <label>
      <strong>Test Bar1</strong>       
    </label>
    <svg height="24" width="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grayGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f5f5f5" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e5e5e5" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="greenGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#4dcb00" />
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#286900" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <rect fill="url(#grayGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="12" ry="12" />
      <rect id="greenId" fill="url(#greenGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="0%" height="100%" rx="12" ry="12" />
    </svg>
  
    <label>
      <strong>Test 2 Bar</strong> 
    </label>
    <svg height="24" width="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect fill="url(#grayGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="12" ry="12" />
      <rect id="greenId1" fill="url(#greenGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="0%" height="100%" rx="12" ry="12" />
    </svg>
  </template>
```

Comment: The template has hardcoded id values so if you use it more than once on a page you'll have duplicate id values. That's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Like commented you cannot have duplicate id values.

Move the defs element out into is own SVG. The SVG should be hidden (here I set the width and the height to `0`). Remove id values from the rect elements in the template and use class names instead.

```js
const menu = document.getElementById('bars');
const temp1 = document.getElementById('temp1');

addbar('Test bar 1', 70);
addbar('Test bar 2', 33);

function addbar(label, width){
  let clone = temp1.content.cloneNode(true);
  clone.querySelector('label strong').textContent = label;
  clone.querySelector('.greenbar').setAttribute('width', `${width}%`);
  menu.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
div#bars {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="bars">
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grayGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#f5f5f5" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#e5e5e5" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="greenGradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#4dcb00" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#286900" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>

<template id="temp1">
  <label>
    <strong>Title</strong>       
  </label>
  <svg height="24" width="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="url(#grayGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" rx="12" ry="12" />
    <rect class="greenbar" fill="url(#greenGradient)" x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="100%" rx="12" ry="12" />
  </svg>
</template>
```

Comment: Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cloneNode')]

Answer (score 0):

You can use duplicate `id` values in SVGs when you place the SVG in  ***shadowDOM***.

No need to use LWC - *Lightning Web Components* for that

A **native Web Component** `<gradient-bar>` to *create* the SVG is:

```html
<gradient-bar value="5" start="tomato" stop="red">React</gradient-bar>
<gradient-bar value="30" start="red" stop="orange">Vue</gradient-bar>
<gradient-bar value="70" start="red" stop="green">Svelte</gradient-bar>
<gradient-bar value="100">Native Web Components</gradient-bar>
<style>
  gradient-bar::part(percent) { fill:white; }
</style>

<script>
  customElements.define("gradient-bar", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.style.display = "block";
      let width = this.getAttribute("value") || 50;
      let r = this.getAttribute("r") || 1;
      this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML = `
<style>:host{font-family:arial}</style>
<strong part=title ><slot>[title goes here]</slot></strong>
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 24">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient x2=100% id=back >
      <stop stop-color=#f5f5f5 /><stop stop-color=#e5e5e5 offset=100% />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient x2=100% id=bar >
      <stop stop-color=${this.getAttribute("start")||"#4dcb00"} />
      <stop stop-color=${this.getAttribute("stop") ||"#286900"} offset=100% />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect part=back height=100% rx=${r}% fill=url(#back) width=100% />
  <rect part=bar  height=100% rx=${r}% fill=url(#bar)  width=${width}% />
  <text part=percent x=2 y=73% >${width}%</text>
</svg>`
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: No MODULE named markup://gradient:bar found : [markup://c:testSVG2]

Comment: Just tested it (again) Runs fine in Chrome and Firefox